# Pywinauto control identifiers from source code

Tags: python-3.x, windows, user-interface, pywinauto

**TL;DR:**

Is it possible to retrieve control identifiers in pywinauto from source code? If so, how?

**Verbose:**

I am testing a win executable with pywinauto and I am retrieving the control idenfiers via print_control_identifiers. When I open a different tab or a different child is under scope new control idenfiers appear.

My current solution is writing a "software abstraction layer" as json that provides names that are more human readble than "edit 0", and having someone on the team to mantain such interface. It is time consuming and not the best option. Also, my fear is that a refactored UI (e.g. a button added on some tab) will change completly the name of the already present identifiers.
e.g.

> {   "TGui": {
> "SitesPage":
> {
> "firstSite": "Static2",
> "homeButton": "designTabItem",
> "descriptionForm": "Site:2",
> "siteName":"Edit0",
> "siteDescription":"Edit0",
> }
> }
> }

I'd like to reduce the time needed to identify such identifiers starting from the source code when it will be availlale for my team. Is it possible? Or as an alternative, is it possible to get the control identifier clicking on it (something similar to pyautogui.displayMousePosition()).

Comment: Do you mean source code of the target application? It depends which GUI framework is used. For example, WPF or WinForms elements provide its programmatic name in `automation_id` property (`auto_id` keyword in `child_window` specification in pywinauto) for `backend="uia"`. But I don't understand how is it connected with getting mouse position? Please clarify.

Comment: It's an example. With pyautogui.displayMousePosition() I can get the coordinates of where I click. I would like to be able to click on an element of the GUI and print the programmatic name. I'd like to avoid the manual inspection via trial and error of the control idenfiers.